# Smooth Transition Between Frames in WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I wonder if it is possible to make transitions between frames smoother in WxPython.

For now I use the classical "self.Destroy" and "self.GetParent().Show()" methods to implement this task. But transitions are sharp. And it just doesnt look nice to my eyes.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you're Destroying the frame. Just hide / show it. Or use a "fade in" / "fade out" effect to make it look cooler. When it fades out all the way, hide the frame and vice-versa. See http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/04/14/doing-a-fade-in-with-wxpython/ for an example of the fading effect.